# VSCode - Get error after turn on Settings Sync with GitHub

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Windows 11 after incorrect vscode (1.66.2) uninstall get error for turn on Settings Sync with GitHub - "Error while turning on Settings Sync. Cancelled". DO not redirect to a browser to login to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean the "**Microsoft authentication provider is not available**" or the "**Error while turning on settings sync. No authentication providers are available**" errors.

Here is what solved the issue for me:

1. Uninstall VSCode
2. [Remove old VSCode entries from the Windows Credential Manager](https://www.cloudnotes.io/microsoft-authentication-provider-is-not-available-vscode-settings-sync-aadsts700003/)
3. Remove all of [VSCode folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall) that remain after uninstalling (i.e., do a clean uninstall)
4. Download the latest version of VSCode (the system version and not the user one)
5. Re-install VSCode and try to sign in once the installation is done

The issue now should be gone.